# Disable Touchscreen in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: 23.10

I have a touchscreen Hp Laptop and using the Ubuntu 23.10 os i dont know how to disable the touchscreen. i have tried the methods for other Ubuntu versions but they seem not to work for 23.10 im new to linux. does anyone know how to do it ?